# Form Hanging on Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have a form that hangs on the third field, meaning the the third field is not triggering any validation if left empty (website). Because I can't get past this, I am not sure if the form will even send an email (so I may have two problems). Any help would be appreciated (very much).

**UPDATE**

The validation problem was solved by Asfer, any assistance with the form not sending an email would be great, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

**HTML** (`contact.html`)

```
<style>
#send_message { 
    width:200px !important; 
    font-variant: small-caps; 
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#3399FF;
    color:#FFFFFF;
} 
.error { 
    display: none; 
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px;
    padding:5px; 
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    color: #D8000C; 
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
}
.success { 
    display: none; 
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 1px;
    padding:5px; 
    color: #044406; 
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: #B7FBB9;
}
</style>

<form class="form-horizontal" name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action='email.php'>
    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Full Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div id='name_error' class='error'>Please enter your full name</div>
            <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div id='email_error' class='error'>Please enter a valid email address</div>
            <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Website -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="website">Website</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div id='website_error' class='error'>Please enter your website address</div>
            <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="website">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Message -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="message">Enquiry</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div id='message_error' class='error'>Please enter your message</div>
            <textarea class="input-medium" id="message" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div class="form-actions">
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div id='mail_success' class='success'>Your message has been sent successfully</div>
        <div id='mail_fail' class='error'>Sorry, an error has occurred</div>
        <button id='send_message' type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**VALIDATION** (`validation.js`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_message').click(function(e){

        //Stop form submission & check the validation
        e.preventDefault();

        // Variable declaration
        var error = false;
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var website = $('#website').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();

        // Form field validation
        if(name.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
            var error = true;
            $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(subject.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#website_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#website_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(message.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        // If there is no validation error, next to process the mail function
        if(error == false){
           // Disable submit button just after the form processed 1st time successfully.
            $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Sending...' });

            /* Post Ajax function of jQuery to get all the data from the submission of the form as soon as the form sends the values to email.php*/
            $.post("email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                //Check the result set from email.php file.
                if(result == 'sent'){
                    //If the email is sent successfully, remove the submit button
                     $('#submit').remove();
                    //Display the success message
                    $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    //Display the error message
                    $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                    // Enable the submit button again
                    $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Send The Message');
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

**SEND MAIL** (`email.php`)

```
<?php
$to = 'support@example.com';  // Send to
$subject = 'example.com Contact Form'; // Subject of your email

$message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Website: ' . $_REQUEST['website'] . "<br>";
$message .= 'Message: ' $_REQUEST['message'];

$headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
    echo 'sent';
}
else
{
    // Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you learned how to debug? You could at least narrow it down a little?

Comment: Unfortunately not, still getting my feet wet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1) In email.php

```
$message .= 'Message: ' $_REQUEST['message'];
```

should be

```
$message .= 'Message: ' . $_REQUEST['message'];
```

2) Remove the **.=** for the first assignment lines in email.php to avoid unnecessary notices.
ie:

```
$message = 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
```

and

```
$headers = "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
```

3) If you want to send an HTML email, you will need to add some additional headers. Refer to Example #4 in [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

4) In addition to that, give all of your form fields a **name** attribute.

```
<input type="text" class="input-medium" id="name" name="name">
<input type="text" class="input-medium" id="email" name="email">
<input type="text" class="input-medium" id="website" name="website">
<textarea class="input-medium" id="message" rows="6" name="message"></textarea>
```

5) If you are trying to send this on a machine running a Windows OS, you will likely not have any mail servers running. This will cause the mail() function to fail.

Answer (score 2):

check these lines

1. `var website = $('#website').val();`
2. `if(subject.length == 0){`

I think subject should be website

Comment: Good eye, that solved the validation issue. Sadly when I try to submit the form, I get "Sorry, an error has occurred"

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in line if(subject.length == 0) {

Replace subject by website like if(website.length == 0) {

```
if(name.length == 0){
    var error = true;
    $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
}
if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
    var error = true;
    $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
}

if(subject.length == 0){   //remove this line

if(website.length == 0){   //add this line

    var error = true;
    $('#website_error').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    $('#website_error').fadeOut(500);
}


if(subject.length == 0){
    var error = true;
    $('#website_error').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    $('#website_error').fadeOut(500);
}
if(message.length == 0){
    var error = true;
    $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
}else{
    $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
}
```